# SEO images in Nextgen Galleries

Tags: images, seo, plugin-nextgen-gallery, google-search

I have a couple blogs / wordpress sites that I post pictures on.  I have noticed that most of the pictures  I post with the nextgen gallery plug in never show up in google images search.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you filled out the "alt" tags properly.  The chances of being indexed are less if the tag is not included.  Additionally, the file name for the image should not be "quor7b.jpg" unless it's a photo of a Quor7b. The file name should also reflect the image (e.g. rose.jpg).

Comment: The alt tags have been filled in, but the image names stayed img4056.jpg.  I will try that, and revisit this issue if that does not solve the issue in a month or so.

Comment: @sound2man Hope it helps--Ray